# Override the default og:image on some pages

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, pug

The default og:image is set on the head as follows:

[image]

And according to Facebook Debug (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=plutio.com) everything is set correctly.

However, I've overridden the image on this page: https://plutio.com/partners/shopify and everything seem to be linking to the other image:

[image]

But when sharing that page or using Facebook to debug it, it still show the default image: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fplutio.com%2Fpartners%2Fshopify

Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, the meaning of `og:url`

Comment: @CBroe I should add the link of the image to og:url too?

Comment: No, you just need to stop pointing it to a completely different URL. Right now you are telling Facebook, please go fetch the actual meta data for this piece of content elsewhere ...

Comment: @CBroe you rock, can you post it as the answer so i can mark it resolved? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to point `og:url` to the actual URL of this content.

You had it set to the home page URL, so the Facebook scraper went and fetched the meta data from there.